# update_attributes & update do not call validations on parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So i have the following problem in my codebase.

In database there is data that doesn't satisfy the validations. (its not right I know, and will be fixed but the question remains why rails works like it does)

Calling `save` in `create` action will run validations on the parent object and wont save anything, however, calling the `update` or `update_attributes` in `update` action will not and the object will be saved with invalid parent.

**Model:**

```
class RussianDoll < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :name, :description, presence: true

has_and_belongs_to_many :parents,
                        class_name: 'RussianDoll',
                        join_table: :russian_dolls_russian_dolls,
                        foreign_key: :child_id,
                        association_foreign_key: :parent_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :children,
                        class_name: 'RussianDoll',
                        join_table: :russian_dolls_russian_dolls,
                        foreign_key: :parent_id,
                        association_foreign_key: :child_id

end
```

**Controller:**

```
class RussianDollsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    rd_params = russian_doll_params
    rd_params[:parents] = RussianDoll.where(id: params[:parent_ids])

    @russian_doll = RussianDoll.new(rd_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @russian_doll.save
        format.html { render 'foo' }
        format.xml { render 'bar' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.xml { render xml: @russian_doll.errors }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @russian_doll = RussianDoll.find(params[:id])
    rd_params = russian_doll_params

    rd_params[:parents] = RussianDoll.where(id: params[:parent_ids])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @russian_doll.update(rd_params)
        format.html { render 'foo' }
        format.xml { render 'bar' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.xml { render xml: @russian_doll.errors }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def russian_doll_params
    params.require(:russian_doll).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

When you try to create a new `RussianDoll` (with `name` AND `description`) it wont save if the `RussianDoll` parent you are trying to associate it with doesnt have `description` set in database.
However if you create it without any parents, and then try to add a parent through the `update` action, then you will be able to set association to a `RussianDoll` entry that doesnt have `description` set (invalid entry).

As far as I know `update` should run all validations, same as the `save` action does but it doesn't seem to do that in this case.

Why do `save` validations work, but `update` ones don't?
Any help is appreciated!

[EDIT]

So I finally managed to find the root cause...

In `create` action we first create the `@russian_doll` with already set invalid parent in its association, so if we run `.valid?` on the object it will fail.

However in the `update` action, our `@russian_doll` is being first found in database, and before the `.update(rd_params)` object itself is not being changed, so running `.valid?` will return `true`, and `update` will manage to connect edited `russian_doll` with invalid parent.

What still bugs me, is that second time the `update` is called, `@russian_doll` will have invalid parent from a first `update`, but for some reason `.valid?` is still returning `true`, instead of failing.

**It is like validations work for all nested entries only on object creation...**

Comment: `@russian_doll.valid?` will only ever apply to the model itself; the issue comes when you save the object. From [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference): 
"If you set the :validate option to false, then associated objects will not be validated whenever you save this object. By default, this is true: associated objects will be validated when this object is saved."
The strange thing here is that with the call to update, `@russian_doll` should be saved and hence its parents should be validated.

Comment: @rwold I tried to use binding.pry to debug in runtime, and even before the `@russian_doll.save` is invoked in create action `@russian_doll.valid?` is already returning false. And in update action it is now returning true before the `@russian_doll.update` is invoked. Like it knows it is not a new record and it is not running validation on the parent objects...

Comment: Have a read of section "4.3.4 When are Objects Saved?" [of the Rails AR assoication guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference). Checking for a new record is very much a thing in Rails, and the `save` method may be called earlier than you think.